# Recognize block of data as one block using regex vba

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I am trying to create a pattern for the following text

```
not included

 4680145876 
some text some text ffgg   
 30905102511638 
 1
other text other text

no included
```

Here's my try

```
^\s*\d{6,10}(?:\n(?!\s*\d{1,}\n).*){5}
```

I will be using such a pattern in VBA
The expected output to be highlighted (in five lines)

```
468049876 
some text some text ffgg   
 30905102639638 
 1
other text other text
```

** I have updated the question as I face a problem
Suppose the text like that

```
not included

 468041476 
some text some text ffgg   
 31605102764638 
 1
other text other text
extra line
 416524332 
some text some text ffgg   
 30905103594638 
 1
other text other text
extra line
6354422
no included
```

Here I need the block to follow the sequence:
1- Numbers from 6 to 12 digits
2- Then some text in one line
3- Numbers equals to 14 digits
4- Numbers from 1 to 3 digits
5- Text (this is the problem as this text may be in two lines not one line) and I need to include that extra line as one line
so the output of the text example

```
 468049876 
some text some text ffgg   
 30905103685638 
 1
other text other text extra line
```

and

```
 416524332 
some text some text ffgg   
 30905101497638 
 1
other text other text extra line
```

I mean that text would include two blocks only (each of five lines)

- I am using such a code:

  ```
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True: .MultiLine = True: .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = sPattern
    If .Test(sInput) Then
        Set col = .Execute(sInput)
        For i = 0 To col.Count - 1
            x = Split(col.Item(i), vbLf)
            cnt = cnt + 1
            For j = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
                a(i + 1, j + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(x(j)))
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
  ```

  End With

Now when looping through the matches I got the variable x of more than five items. I expected to get only five items.
How can I pick up the second group of each match separately?

Comment: Your pattern can not cross matching lines that have only digits when you use `(?:\n(?!\s*\d{1,}\n)` so you will not get pass `30905103300638`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you should check for 6-10 digit number in the negative condition, and to match whitespace byt line breaks you can use `[^\S\r\n]`:

```vb
^( *\d{6,12} *\n.*\n *\d{14} *\n *\d{1,3} *)((?:\n(?! *\d{6,10} *$).+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XuDNq5/5). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line (remember to use )
- `(` - Group 1 start:

  - `*` - zero or more spaces
  - `\d{6,10}` - six to ten digits
  - `*` - zero or more spaces
  - `\n.*` - a line
  - `\n *\d{14} *` - a line with 14 digits enclosed with zero or more spaces
  - `\n *\d{1,3} *` - a line with one to three digits enclosed with zero or more spaces
- `)` - end of Group 1
- `((?:\n(?! *\d{6,10} *$).+)*)` - Group 2:

  - `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

    - `\n` - an LF line ending
    - `(?! *\d{6,12} *$)` - not immediately followed with zero or more spaces, six to twelve digits, zero or more spaces and end of a line
    - `.+` - a non-empty line (one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `)*` - end of the grouping, zero or more occurrences.
- `)` - end of Group 2.

After getting matches, Group 2 contains the last block of lines, so you can manipulate that text as much as you want, and then concatenate with Group 1 value.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain the pattern `^ *\d{6,10} *(?:\n(?! *\d{6,10} *\n).+)*` as this is simpler and it works for me?

Comment: @YasserKhalil It is the same as the other one. Just a space matches a space, `\n` matches a line feed char.

Comment: I faced a problem as for last line, sometimes the last line `other text other text` is on two lines and I need it to be the last line so the block should start with 6 to 9 digits and extend for five lines only .. and if the last line followed by a text on anew line to include the extra line to the last line.

Comment: Question updated to explain the last comment.

Comment: @YasserKhalil I think [it is still working](https://regex101.com/r/XuDNq5/3).

Comment: Yes, it is working as highlighting the block. What I am trying to do in the code to split the block so as to put each line in a column and in the case of the extra line I got 6 lines not five lines and at the same time, I need the sixth line to be joined to the fifth line. It seems I have to resolve that point through the code

Comment: Another point ` 6354422
no included`, this is not applicable to the conditions of the pattern needed. The pattern should be applicable to the conditions I mentioned in the update.

Comment: @YasserKhalil I added an updated solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last note, I note that the match is of two groups and the second group is the last line. The last line if has multiple lines, it should include text-only not numbers nor dates

Comment: @YasserKhalil Replace `.+` with `[^\d\n]+`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EYyMyT/1).

Comment: How can I pick the second group of the pattern .. Update the question to post the code I am using?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip. I will try to solve that point based on your tip.

Comment: I tried this in the code to see the contents `Debug.Print col.Submatches(1)` but throws an error.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Sure, it is because it is a match collection. You will need to access each match separately, `col.Item(i).Submatches(...)`

Comment: I tried first to loop using `For i = 0 To col.Submatches.Count - 1` but seems that is not correct. What is inside (...) what does this should refer to?

Comment: I tried to declare m as an object then I used this `For Each m In col.SubMatches` but it throws error too.

Comment: @YasserKhalil `0` is Group 1, `1` is Group 2. If you need to handle newlines differently in Group 1 and Group 2, process them one after another: `For i = 0 To col.Count - 1 x = Split(col.Item(i).Submatches(0), vbLf)....` and then `x = Split(col.Item(i).Submatches(1), vbLf)....`

Comment: Thank you very much for the great and awesome support in this issue. Best Regards

Comment: I am dealing with about 50 pages, and I found that the text in the second line sometimes has an extra line. Can it be grouped also as we did with the last line so as to join it later in the code in one line?

Comment: I played around and I think this is working `^( *\d{6,12} *\n)(.*\n?.*\n)( *\d{14} *\n *\d{1,3} *)((?:\n(?! *\d{6,10} *$)[^\d\n]+)*)`. Please have a look.

Comment: @YasserKhalil `^( *\d{6,12} *\n)(.*\n(?:.*\n)?)( *\d{14} *\n *\d{1,3} *)((?:\n(?! *\d{6,10} *$)[^\d\n]+)*)`